# How to fix an SPI driver that always fails validation in the Linux kernel SPI driver

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, embedded-linux, spi

I am running embedded Linux (4.14.16) built with Yocto (Pyro).  I am running on a custom board that has an i.MX6DL and the SPI is connected to an FPGA (a Xilinx Artix 7).  I am currently writing a class that is part of an abstraction layer, so this code sits on top of the Linux drivers.  It isn't a Linux device driver.  The SPI works; I can program the FPGA with a shell script, and see the SPI traffic if echo data into /dev/spi1.0 (the FPGA brings out the SPI to a header, which I have an analyzer hooked up to).

The issue is when I use my driver to try to read registers in the FPGA, it isn't sending anything; the SPI transfer doesn't happen.

I dug into the spidev and spi drivers in Linux a little bit, and I am seeing it fail the `__spi_validate` call in drivers/spi/spi.c right under the `/* check transfer rx_nbits */` comment.  What controls those bits?  Everything on our board is single data bit per clock, we have no quad-spi.

Here is the code in question:

```cpp
#include "os/drivers/buses/linuxos/spi_driver.h"

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

namespace os
{
namespace drivers
{
namespace buses
{
namespace linuxos
{
spi_driver::spi_driver(int bus_id, int cs_index, std::uint32_t speed_bps) :
    m_speed_bps(speed_bps)
{
    std::stringstream descriptor;
    descriptor << "/dev/spidev" << bus_id << '.' << cs_index;
    m_device_file_descriptor = descriptor.str();
}

bool spi_driver::transfer(const unsigned char *out_data, unsigned char *in_data, size_t size_in_bytes)
{
    int spi_file_handle = open(m_device_file_descriptor.c_str(), O_RDWR);
    bool success = (spi_file_handle >= 0);

    if (success)
    {
        printf("spidev opened\n");
        struct spi_ioc_transfer transfer_parameters;
        transfer_parameters.tx_buf = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(out_data);
        transfer_parameters.rx_buf = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(in_data);
        transfer_parameters.len = size_in_bytes;
        transfer_parameters.speed_hz = m_speed_bps;
        transfer_parameters.bits_per_word = 0;
        // transfer_parameters.cs_change = 0;
        // transfer_parameters.delay_usecs = 0;

        int ioctl_return = ioctl(spi_file_handle, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &transfer_parameters);

        printf("spidev ioctl returned %d\n", ioctl_return);

        success = (ioctl_return > 0);

        printf("Received data: ");
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size_in_bytes; i++)
        {
            printf("%02x ", in_data[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    close(spi_file_handle);

    return success;
}
}
}
}
}
```

I am not sure if it is relevant (the SPI appears to work...) but here is the SPI part of the device tree.

```
&ecspi2 {
    cs-gpios = <&gpio5 12 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ecspi2 &pinctrl_ecspi2_cs>;
    status = "okay";

    simulator-fpga {
        compatible = "mi,simulator-fpga";
        spi-max-frequency = <8000000>;
        reg = <0>;
    };
};
```

The *mi,simulator-fpga* has been added to the generic spidev driver's compatible string, since it prints an error if you use spidev directly, but it is the generic spidev device.

I did try just using the Linux read and write functions, which worked (I saw the traffic on the SPI analyzer), but I need full duplex transfers which can't be done via that method.

Edit: In case anyone is wondering what those printf statements print out, here is what I get from those:

```
spidev opened
spidev ioctl returned -1
Received data: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The Received data is the correct length for the desired message being sent.  I am not sure why this is getting -1 for a return value, the error thrown in spi.c in the kernel is -22 (EINVAL/Invalid argument) as noted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not sure why this is required, but this version of the driver appears to work. I added all the extra ioctls that were in [this example.](https://armbedded.taskit.de/node/318)
 While my FPGA still doesn't like the output (even though it worked fine with 3.14), it looks correct on the logic analyzer and via a protocol analyzer.

```cpp
#include "os/drivers/buses/linuxos/spi_driver.h"

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

namespace os
{
namespace drivers
{
namespace buses
{
namespace linuxos
{
spi_driver::spi_driver(int bus_id, int cs_index, std::uint32_t speed_bps) :
    m_speed_bps(speed_bps)
{
    std::stringstream descriptor;
    descriptor << "/dev/spidev" << bus_id << '.' << cs_index;
    m_device_file_descriptor = descriptor.str();
}

bool spi_driver::transfer(const unsigned char *out_data, unsigned char *in_data, size_t size_in_bytes)
{
    int spi_file_handle = open(m_device_file_descriptor.c_str(), O_RDWR);
    bool success = (spi_file_handle >= 0);

    const std::uint8_t mode = 3;
    const std::uint8_t bits = 8;
    int ioctl_return = 0;

    if (success)
    {
        ioctl_return = ioctl(spi_file_handle, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);
        if (ioctl_return != 0)
            success = false;

        ioctl_return = ioctl(spi_file_handle, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &mode);
        if (ioctl_return != 0)
            success = false;

        ioctl_return = ioctl(spi_file_handle, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
        if (ioctl_return != 0)
            success = false;

        ioctl_return = ioctl(spi_file_handle, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
        if (ioctl_return != 0)
            success = false;

        ioctl_return = ioctl(spi_file_handle, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &m_speed_bps);
        if (ioctl_return != 0)
            success = false;

        ioctl_return = ioctl(spi_file_handle, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &m_speed_bps);
        if (ioctl_return != 0)
            success = false;
    }

    if (success)
    {
        struct spi_ioc_transfer tr;
        tr.tx_buf = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(out_data);
        tr.rx_buf = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(in_data);
        tr.len = size_in_bytes;
        tr.delay_usecs = 0;
        tr.speed_hz = 0;
        tr.bits_per_word = 0;

        ioctl_return = ioctl(spi_file_handle, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
        success = (ioctl_return != 1);
    }

    close(spi_file_handle);

    return success;
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: The reason my FPGA didn't like it is because the FPGA was expecting mode 0, not mode 3